# Secured tag of Spring Web Flow: How to pass Flow scope parameter to a Spring bean method?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow, spring-el

I'm securing Spring Web Flow states with Spring security. In the `secured` tag I'm calling a method of a Spring bean and trying to pass a Flow scope parameter to it. Everything works fine except the passing of the Flow scope parameter - null is passed.

This is the snippet from the Web Flow xml:

```
<action-state id="securedAction">
    <secured attributes="@myAction.accessGranted(#flowScope.parameter)" />
    ...
    ...
</action-state>
```

How to pass the Flow scope parameter?

Comment: have you tied flowScope.parameter without the #?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my own question - instead of trying to pass the flow scoped parameter from the flow via the Java method parameters, it can be fetched via `org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder` in the called method:

```
RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getFlowScope().get("parameter");
```

P.S.:
If you want to set a flow scoped parameter use

```
RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getFlowScope().put("parameter", myParameterObject);
```